# Problemas plantilla admin lte

Tags: css

Buenas mi duda era sobre como hago para cambiarle el fondo al login de la plantilla admin lte  quiero ponerle una imagen como fondo.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Las preguntas sin código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.

Comment: Lo que te recomiendo es estudiar css. asi crearas o modificaras cualquier template

Answer (score 1):

la plantilla AdminLTE viene con una hoja de estilos CSS llamada custom.css, ahí puedes aplicar estilos para lograr lo que quieres. para colocar una imagen de fondo en la vista de login, usa el siguiente código:

```css
background: url('ruta/hacia/tu/imagen/);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: auto;
```

Estos estilos normalmente se aplicación al body, pero si lo haces seguramente también verás la imagen de fondo al hacer login. Para evitar eso te sugiero que encierres el contenido del login un div por ejemplo, y a este div le aplicas los estilos.

Me comentas si te funcionó :)

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, ayudanos a responder preguntas que sean realizadas en base a lo definido en el [help], especificamente [ask] y ayudar al OP a mejorar sus preguntas, saludos.